# Code not working properly after "building"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make so when character touches spikes, then checkpoint value sets to 1 and when it touches flag, then it dies(i added tag "Spikes1" to spikes and tag "Flag" to flag).

I tried adding text to canvas to see if the code works at all(debug.text is that text).

Code:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin") {
            debug.text = "Coin touched";
            Health = Health - 1;
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Spikes1") {
            debug.text = "Spikes touched";
            CheckPointNumber = 1;
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Flag") {
            debug.text = "Flag touched";
            Health = 0;
        }
        JumpActive = true;
    }
```

Everything works fine in Unity itself, but when i build the game and run it as an exe file and touch spikes it acts like i touched flag and when i touch flag nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like a logic error, you probably want `Health = 0;` in the block with condition `col.gameObject.tag == "Spikes1"`. So swap `CheckPointNumber = 1;` and `Health = 0;`.

Comment: check you variable names. i think you used them in wrong place

Comment: Tip: use `.CompareTag("Coin")` instead of `.tag == "Coin"`, it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to follow some principles of the Survival Shooter example from Unity3D site?
There you will find a Player's Health section showing how you should properly handles the player's health: [Survival Shooter Training](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/survival-shooter-training-day-phases?projectId=5c514921edbc2a002069465e#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b71e)

In your code, I can see that you are decreasing the Health each time it hits the "Coin", so you should put some check like this:

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin") {
    debug.text = "Coin touched";

    if (Health > 0)
    {
        Health--;
    }
    else
    {
        Death();
    }
}
```

Where Death() is a function that you need to program in order to "kill" your character.
You should apply the same behavior on the "Flag" tag check by calling Death() instead of making Health equals 0.

Regarding the wrong behavior, check if the tag of the object being touched is correctly filled. Maybe the flag is configured to run as a spike.

Hope that helps.